# GMSMapView - Mimic camera animation like Google Maps Application

Tags: ios, gmsmapview

I'm implementing google maps sdk in my app.

However, the build in map animation is not even close to be like the animation which can be seen in Google Maps application.

The animation in Google Maps application is very smooth and modest.
The build in map animation is very jumpy and aggressive.

The animation code is:

```
let newPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: location, zoom: self.defaultZoom)
self.mapView.animate(to: newPosition)
```

- I'm not talking about the Duration of the animation which can be controlled with the Core animations. I'm talking about the animation itself.

Comment: did u get any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

With the Core animation you can control not only Duration, also you can setup timing function(kCATransactionAnimationTimingFunction) and you can use function few [provided](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Timing_Functions) by Apple (EaseIn/EaseOut etc) or you can make custom functions like [this](https://gist.github.com/nuthinking/7415509)